# TCPDF Indent issue with justified align

Tags: tcpdf

A developer created a TCPDF form for me because I had too many other projects to work on and no experience with TCPDF. I have a small issue that I need some help figuring out. The first line of each paragraph needs to be indented a half-inch, but the paragraph needs to be align justified. Because of the justified alignment, the indentation is thrown off and the paragraphs don't match. Is there a way to resolve this?

[image: Output]

```
$pdf = new MyPDF();
$intergine = 10;
$indent = str_repeat(" ", 10);
$indent_html = str_repeat("&nbsp;", 10);
$pdf->AddPage("P", array(215.9, 279.4));
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'BU', 14);
$pdf->Cell(0, 6, "TEST CONTRACT", 0, 1, "C");

$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->setCellHeightRatio(2.4);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 12);
//$pdf->MultiCell(0, $intergine, $indent . "Client(s): [contracts.clientName]\n", 0, 'J', 0, 12);

$clientname = "Client(s): <u>". $row['clientName']."</u>";
$pdf->MultiCell(0, $intergine, $indent . $clientname . "\n", 0, 'J', 0, 12, '45', '', true, 0, true);


$paragraph = "I hereby retain and employ the Law Office of John Smith, Attorney ";
$paragraph .= "at Law, 123 Main St, Tallahassee, FL 33333 ";
$paragraph .= "as my attorney to represent me in a cause of action against ";
$paragraph .= $row['insuranceCo'] . " or any other entity based on my flood claim, including any ";
$paragraph .= "and all building, contents and ICC claims, which occurred on or about ";
$paragraph .= $row['lossDate'] . " at or near " .  $row['lossLocation'] . ".";
$pdf->MultiCell(0, $intergine, $indent_html . $paragraph . "\n", 0, 'J', 0, 1, '', '', true, 0, true);

$paragraph = "As compensation for their services, I agree that my attorneys may pay ";
$paragraph .= "themselves from the gross amount of the recovery, before any sums whatsoever ";
$paragraph .= "are deducted from said gross amount of recovery for costs or other items, a ";
$paragraph .= "contingent fee based upon the following percentages of the gross amount of such recovery:";
$pdf->MultiCell(0, $intergine, $indent . $paragraph . "\n", 0, 'J', 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research combined with trial and error, I learned to use $writeHTMLCell and the indent style which worked perfectly.

Comment: Would you share your solution here?